# Extjs hasone association

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, model, associations

I have Person model, it contains id, first_name, last_name etc and **merital_id** field. I also have Merital model contains only 2 field: id and title.
Server responses JSON like:

```
{
    success: true,
    items: [
        {
            "id":"17",
            "last_name":"Smith",
            "first_name":"John",
            ...
            "marital_id":1,
            "marital": {
                "id":1,
                "title":"Female"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

So how can I connect my models with association? I still can use record.raw.merital.title in my column.renderer, but I cannot use such fields in templates like {last_name} {first_name} ({merital.title}).
What king of association do I need to use, I tryed belongsTo, but when I try to use record.getMarital() I get an error "no such method on record".

I use extjs 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using ExtJS Models, and Associations, in particular the HasOne association.

Documentation:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasOne

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/el_chief/yrTVn/2/

```
Ext.define('Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name'
        ],

    hasOne: [
        {
        name: 'marital',
        model: 'Marital',
        associationKey: 'marital' // <- this is the same as what is in the JSON response
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'whatever',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items' // <- same as in the JSON response
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, but I use Sencha Architect, and I do not see such kind of association in property grid (

Comment: Hm, but every time I deploy my project it will disappear?

Comment: Sencha Architect is supposed to support in-line code editing. Perhaps it is not in this update yet?

Comment: In Sencha Architect, we can associate different models using `Association` Config. When you click on '+' button, it would ask you for `Has Many` or `Has One` association. We can select model, name and associatedKey after that.